# Flex DataGrid: Get Data Object from row index & vice versa?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, datagrid, dataprovider

Using a standard Flex DataGrid, is there an easy way to determine the grid row index given the data object or index of the data object in the data provider? On the flip side, is there a way to get the index of an object in the data provider based on the DataGrid row index? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you're asking for correctly and assuming your `dataProvider` is an `ArrayCollection`:

**To get the selected row's index in your dataProvider:**

```
var rowIndex:int = myArrayCollection.getItemIndex(myDataGrid.selectedItem);
```

**To get the object in your dataProvider from the DataGrid:**

```
var obj:Object = myDataGrid.selectedItem;
```

Since DataGrid's recycle their `itemRenderers` to improve memory performance, there's no specific row index for a given object in your `dataProvider`. As you scroll and records are no longer visible, those records `itemRenderers` are reused for new records that scroll into view. You can read up more on `itemRenderers` and recycling [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/itemrenderers_pt1.html).

**EDIT:**
Here's a link to an example on how to filter your data in a dataGrid:

http://www.flex-blog.com/arraycollection-filter-example/

Comment: Is the index in the data provider always going to be the row index though? I figured there would be some built-in options like paging or filtering that would make the grid hide some of the rows. Perhaps that is never the case though (I'm new to Flex so I'm not sure).

Comment: @Ocelot20, No the index in the dataProvider will not always be the row index. That first example I posted will get you the row index in the dataProvider for the selected row in your dataGrid. Unfortunately, the Flex dataGrid doesn't support paging and all filtering is done against your ArrayCollection using filterFunctions. I've added a link to a filtering example in my answer. I hope this helps!